# Select non duplicate records only in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with below records:

```
 ID    Date        
 ------------------
 20    03/07/2017                        
 30    03/07/2017                                                    
 30    17/07/2017                            
 40    24/07/2017                            
 50    24/07/2017
```

Now the required result set should be as below:

```
 ID    Date        
 ------------------
 20    03/07/2017                                              
 40    24/07/2017                            
 50    24/07/2017
```

What I am trying to do is select records where the ID appears only once. Therefore in the example above, ID = 30 was excluded. How do I write a query that does that?

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/distinct.php

Comment: @Deltharis `DISTINCT` alone is not the answer here, since the "Date" values vary between the "duplicates".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one easy way, assuming you are selecting from a table and not a view.

```
SELECT ID, "Date"
FROM   your_table a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'another record with same ID'
                    FROM   your_table b
                    WHERE  b.id = a.id
                    AND    b.rowid != a.rowid )
```

Another way, that works in more cases:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  id IN (SELECT b.id
              FROM   your_table b
              GROUP BY b.id
              HAVING COUNT (*) = 1)
```